# How To Copy Files In Directory and Return Zip - Working Example with Two Issues

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Project Structure:**

```
./theme-generator
│
└───netlify/functions/generator
│    │   generator.js
│
└───template
│    │   index.php
│
└───theme
│    │   index.php
│
└───app.js
```

`app.js` makes a fetch() to `generator.js`.

`generator.js` is responsible for taking the `/template` directory,  copying it over to the `/theme` directory and returning it as a zip.

The below gist shows the `generator.js` code:

https://gist.github.com/joseph-farruggio/41b1181bc30698f2e9d160c26f6b44c6

**Just one problem with this code:**

The zip is returned from a JS fetch(). The first fetch returns an empty zip, if you initiate a second fetch you will get the zip with its contents.

Comment: For item 1, I'm guessing it's because that's the directory you gave it. You'd need to provide a relative path for it to work the way you want. `zip.file()`'s arguments are the path as you want it in the zip and the file content.

Comment: Yup! Issue #1 is officially solved.

Now on to #2.